# How simplify repeat conditional Statements on different seclcet?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(function() {

  if ($("#option1").text().length > 20) {
    $("#option1").css("font-size", "15px")
  }
  if ($("#option2").text().length > 20) {
    $("#option2").css("font-size", "15px")
  }
  if ($("#option3").text().length > 20) {
    $("#option3").css("font-size", "15px")
  }
  if ($("#option4").text().length > 20) {
    $("#option4").css("font-size", "15px")
  }
})
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="option1">1</button><br>
<button id="option2">2</button><br>
<button id="option3">3</button><br>
<button id="option4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, ea. Quisquam doloremque,
        neque, nobis voluptas obcaecati eius commodi quidem et maiores modi odio assumenda cum iusto iste, a adipisci
        repellendus!</button>
```

What write more easy read ? i try above write.
 `if (($("#option1") ||  $("#option2") ||  $("#option3") || $("#option4")).text().length > 20) { //    here i have no idea . i wnat to textlength>20 option font-size become small but here "this" not work}`

thanks.

by the way . font-size min is 15px? i try 15px under seem not work.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to create a html `class` and iterate the same logic over the array that is returned by it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through each button using `each loop` and then use `this` to get length of button and then apply `css` to same .

***Demo code*** :

```js
$(function() {

  //loop thorugh each  button
  $("button").each(function() {
    //check for length
    if ($(this).text().length > 20) {
      //apply css
      $(this).css("font-size", "25px")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="option1">1</button><br>
<button id="option2">2</button><br>
<button id="option3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, ea. Quisquam doloremque,
        neque, nobis voluptas obcaecati</button><br>
<button id="option4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, ea. Quisquam doloremque,
        neque, nobis voluptas obcaecati eius commodi quidem et maiores modi odio assumenda cum iusto iste, a adipisci
        repellendus!</button>
```

To do same onclick of button you can use below code :

```js
$(function() {
//on click of button
  $("button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).text().length > 20) {
      //apply css
      $(this).css("font-size", "25px")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
button {
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button id="option1">1</button><br>
<button id="option2">2</button><br>
<button id="option3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, ea. Quisquam doloremque,
        neque, nobis voluptas obcaecati</button><br>
<button id="option4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus, ea. Quisquam doloremque,
        neque, nobis voluptas obcaecati eius commodi quidem et maiores modi odio assumenda cum iusto iste, a adipisci
        repellendus!</button>
```

Comment: thank you a lot. i love you. let me learn new code ".each" for me .